# Change file name to uniqid in PHP

Tags: php, file

I am looking to modify my code below to accept a randomly generated unique id to replace the name using php uniqid function. I have tried a couple ways with no success.

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
 "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $ipath = "upload/";
 $ipath .= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Edit: I am asking where to put the uniqid function so that the file is stored with the uniqid.extension in the folder on my server.

Comment: Is your question about how to generate the unique file name, or where to put it in the `move_uploaded_file` call?

Comment: I am asking where to put the uniqid function.

Comment: Ok then, @Connun gave you the answer

Comment: @user981053 Actually, I don't quite get what was the problem here... `I have tried a couple ways with no success.`
After all, it's just getting the file extension and simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "upload/" . uniqid());
```

or, if you want to keep the file extension:

```
$fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "upload/" . uniqid() . '.' . $fileInfo['extension']);
```

\\edit: to use the $ipath variable...

```
$fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$ipath = "upload/" . uniqid() . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $ipath);
```

Comment: edited to use the actual file name instead of the temp file name to retrieve the file extension

Comment: Do you know how I can set ipath to equal the new file name?

Answer (score 1):

```
$newName = md5_file($ipath);
```

Will generate the md5 of the file content, should be pretty unique.

Answer (score -2):

```
$aaa = uniqid();
$Image_New_Name = $aaa."_".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] );
$target_dir = "upload/".$Image_New_Name;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] ); 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir )) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) ." has been uploaded.";
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    $id       = $_POST['id'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $gender   = $_POST['gender'];
    $about_me = $_POST['about_me'];
    $state    = $_POST['state'];
    $country  = $_POST['country'];


    if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] != "") {
        $image = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    } else {
        $image='BlankFaceGraphic.jpg';
    }

    $sql="insert into register(id,fullname,password,email,gender,about_me,state,country,image)
                        values
  ('$id','$fullname','$password','$email','$gender','$about_me','$state','$country','$Image_New_Name')";
```