# PHP File Upload is not working in my Bootstrap website's form

Tags: php, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-file-upload, jquery-validation-engine

I have one form in my bootstrap website My HTML CODE is this :my HTML & Javascript code is shown below.
my file is not uploading into the folder .

To see the screenshot of the error please click below link

https://scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/13156_1406728189552147_6450217638090433195_n.jpg?oh=f291d7e5af34a75ce247287cb44368b9&oe=54D7F314

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#register-form").validationEngine();
    $("#register-form").on("submit", function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#register-form").validationEngine('validate')) 
        {
            var form_data = $("form").serialize();
            $.post("insert1.php", {form_values: form_data}, function (data) 
            {
                var Data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $(".registration_form").hide(200);
                $(".success_msg").show(200, function () 
                {
                    $(".result").show();
                    $("td#First_name").html(Data[0].First_name);
                    $("#Last_name").html(Data[0].Last_name);
                    $("#Email").html(Data[0].Email);
                    $("#Contact_no").html(Data[0].Contact_no);
                    $("#Jobseeker_type").html(Data[0].Jobseeker_type);
                });
            });

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css">
</head>
<div class="registration_form">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="insert1.php" method="POST" name="register-form"  id="register-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name"           data-validation-engine="validate[required]" data-errormessage-value-missing="First Name is required!" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name"  data-validation-engine="validate[required]" data-errormessage-value-missing="Last Name is required!" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Email" data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[email]]" data-errormessage-value-missing="Your Email is required!" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact No:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="tel" name="contact" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="Phone" data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[phone]]" data-errormessage-value-missing="Your Contact No is required!" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Jobseeker Type:</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="jobseeker" id="jobseeker1" value="student" data-validation-engine="validate[required]"
                           data-errormessage-value-missing="Please Select any one option">Student
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="jobseeker" id="jobseeker2" value="fresher" data-validation-engine="validate[required]"  data-errormessage-value-missing="Please Select any one option">Fresher
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="jobseeker" id="jobseeker3" value="experienced" data-validation-engine="validate[required]"  data-errormessage-value-missing="Please Select any one option">Experienced
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=""  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload your Resume:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image"   class="form-control"     data-validation-engine="validate[required, custom[checkFileType[image/jpeg|image/png]]]" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please upload your Resume!"  >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="register" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div><!-- end for class "registration_form" --

<script  src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script  src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
```

my php file is shown here

```html
<?php
$errors = array();
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name'])));
$extensions = array("jpeg", "png");
$fileInfo = pathinfo($file_name);
$ipath = "resumes/" . uniqid() . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $ipath);

if (isset($_POST["form_values"])) {
    $form_data = urldecode($_POST["form_values"]);

    preg_match_all('#(\w+)=([^&=]*)(?:&|$)#', $form_data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $result = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        list(, $key, $value) = $m;
        if (!strlen($value)) {
            $i = (int) $key;
        } else {
            $result[$i][$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    require_once("db1.php");

    $fname = $result[0]["fname"];
    $lname = $result[0]["lname"];
    $username = ($result[0]["username"]);
    $contact = $result[0]["contact"];
    $jobseeker = $result[0]["jobseeker"];
    $image = $result[0]["image"];


    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users (First_name, Last_name, Email, Contact_no, Jobseeker_type) VALUES (
                    :fname,
                    :lname,
                    :username,
                    :contact,
                    :jobseeker
                )";

    try {

        $query_insert = $db->prepare($sql_insert);
        $result_insert = $query_insert->execute(array(
            ':fname' => $fname,
            ':lname' => $lname,
            ':username' => $username,
            ':contact' => $contact,
            ':jobseeker' => $jobseeker));
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    if ($result_insert) {

        $last_insert_id = $db->lastInsertId();

        $sql_select = "SELECT
                                First_name,
                                Last_name,
                                Email,
                                Contact_no,
                                Jobseeker_type
                           FROM users
                           WHERE
                           id = :id";


        try {

            $query_select = $db->prepare($sql_select);
            $query_select->execute(array(':id' => $last_insert_id));
            $results = $query_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $json = json_encode($results);
            echo $json;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

        //echo "You are successfully registered.";
    } else {
        echo "error occured";
    }
}
?>
```

I am using jquery validation engine to validate MIME files i have included below code in my jquery.validationEngine.js file

```js
case "checkFileType":
    errorMsg = methods._checkFileType(field, rules, i, options);
break;
_checkFileType: function(field, rules, i, options)
{
    //add to input tag: data-validation-engine="validate[required, custom[validateMIME[image/jpeg|image/png]]]"

    var fileInput = field[0].files[0];
    var MimeFilter = new RegExp(rules[3], 'i');
    if (fileInput) 
    {
        return MimeFilter.test(fileInput.type);
    }
    else 
    {
        return true; 
    }
},
```

and below code into jquery.validationEngine-en.js

```js
"checkFileType": 
{
    "regex": "none",
    "alertText": "* Wrong file Type."                    
},
```

still file is not uploading in my "resume" folder i will appreciate quick reply

Comment: Did you debug your code a bit? In the PHP code, what does `$ipath`, or even `$_FILES`, return? Is it working well until there?

Comment: yes that php code is working i have uploaded file through that code before

Comment: What does `$ipath`, or even `$_FILES`, return?

Comment: read this post to understand it         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810656/change-file-name-to-uniqid-in-php

Comment: I was asking in this particular case when it does not work, what does it return.

Comment: when it didnt work it shown this error click this link it has snapshot of error   https://scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/13156_1406728189552147_6450217638090433195_n.jpg?oh=f291d7e5af34a75ce247287cb44368b9&oe=54D7F314

Comment: Okay file type error solved but now file is not uploading into the folder